# Running Selenium tests on a different machine from TeamCity build agent

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, teamcity-9.0, build-agent

We have TeamCity build agent on Machine-1 and I would like to run Selenium tests that are on a different machine (Machine-2) with this build agent. I am not sure if it is possible to do so.

Also if it is possible where does the tests actually run? 
Is it on Machine-1 or Machine-2?

I tried to research on it, but without success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run Selenium Tests on Machine 2 then you need to install new TeamCity Agent on Machine 2.

Then only you will able to run the tests on Machine 2.

You can't run the test on Machine-1 from TeamCity Agent which is installed on Machine-2.